# How to Clone Kendo Multiselect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="target-elements">

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name("required")
      .Placeholder("Select attendees...")
      .BindTo(new List<string>() {
          "Steven White",
          "Nancy King",
          "Anne King",
          "Nancy Davolio",
          "Robert Davolio",
          "Michael Leverling",
          "Andrew Callahan",
          "Michael Suyama",
          "Anne King",
          "Laura Peacock",
          "Robert Fuller",
          "Janet White",
          "Nancy Leverling",
          "Robert Buchanan",
          "Andrew Fuller",
          "Anne Davolio",
          "Andrew Suyama",
          "Nige Buchanan",
          "Laura Fuller"
      })
      .Value(new string[] { "Anne King", "Andrew Fuller" })
)
```

I'm using `<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>` button to add it dynamically.

This is my HTML Page in MVC I want to clone this multiselect at run time.

I'm using following javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function cloneTargetBox() {
    debugger;
    var targetBoxClone = $(".target-elements:first").clone();
    targetBoxClone.find("input").val("");
    targetBoxClone.insertAfter(".target-elements:last")
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(cloneTargetBox);
});
```

It is working if i'm using normal dropdown. but in kendo new added multiselect is not working.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is it cloning the html?

Comment: Yes it is cloning the html but newly added multiselect is not working. only the old one is working..

Comment: You could try `.clone(true)` (withDataAndEvents) but I suspect you need to attach the plugin to the cloned element - something like `$("#your Element").kendoMultiSelect()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you please provide me some example.

Comment: I'm using Kendo MVC not Kendo-UI. In Kendo-UI we have functionality like var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");

Comment: Yes, but internally that would attach the plugin (probably because it generates a class name used by the kendo script), so you would now need to do it manually since its dynamically added content. And you will also need to inspect the cloned html to make sure your not generating any duplicate `id` attributes

Comment: When it's come to dynamic control, I prefer not to use html helpers(server side) instead do all render things in client side. Try to look knockoutJS to make a dynamic DOM, it make things easier.

Comment: You can use partial views

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this problem. I do not think it can be done. At least, not with .clone(). There are a bunch of issues that arise with the clone, even if you change the id's and names. You will get twin Multiselects (actually, nested), or you'll click in one and the drop down for the one above will open. You can try to do the .clone(true) deep copy as @StephenMueke suggested, but again, that doesn't work. I think the issue is due to the elements of the multiselect that exist in the DOM outside of the cloned area.

I have a workaround that I created from bits and pieces around the web and it might be good as a last resort if you throw up your hands on .clone and still need that multiselect. The steps are:

- Set up a hidden, empty select on the page that will be your destination of the clone.

  ```
   <select style="display:none" id="notYetMultiSelect>
  ```
- Set up your source MultiSelect with a datasource setup however you do that. Give it id="MS".
- in your cloneMultiSelect() method, simply enhance that hidden select as a MultiSelect and give it the datasource of your prexisting source one.

  ```
  // unhide the damn thing or you wont see it.
  $("#notYetMultiSelect").show(); 
  var masterMultiSelect = $("#MS").data('kendoMultiSelect');
  var masterMultiSelectRecords =  masterMultiSelect.dataSource.data().toJSON();
  // enhance as multiselect
  $("#notYetMultiSelect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataTextField: "something",
  dataValueField: "somethingElse",
  placeholder: "whatever",
  dataSource: masterMultiSelectRecords,
  });
  ```

If you want to transfer the values too, go ahead. just use the reference to the master one.